# codeigniter css and js files path

Tags: php, codeigniter

i'm developing a web application with php codeigniter. in views folder, i created header.php that contains css and js and etc files and footer.php for footer of pages.
in default controller, when i use `$this->load->view('header')`, it's Ok. but when i use this command in other pages, css files can not load. in inspect element i've got errors that says in css file path, codeigniter added `index.php/ctrl_name` to this address.

this is path of my css file:

```
http://localhost:9000/CRM/index.php/home/assets/css/materialize.min.css
```

Comment: Please post more of your code.

Comment: Have you set your base url to `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:9000/CRM/'; ` You need to.

Comment: Assets must be out side of application folder.

Answer (score 6):

1. Load url helper in application/config/autoload.php

   `$autoload['helper'] = array('url');`
2. Set base_url config in application/config/config.php

   `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/MyProject';`
3. In header.php, include js and css like this:

   `<link href="<?=base_url();?>assets/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

   Good luck!

Comment: TNX bro! i exactly do this. but not working for other controllers.

Comment: Can you show me your directory order? where do you put that `assets` folder?

Comment: i put this folder in the root of project.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you use relative URLs for your assets, probably something like `'assets/css/materialize.min.css'`.

One possible solution is to use absolute URLs instead:
`base_url('assets/css/materialize.min.css')`

An other solution would be to use a constant to store the path to your assets folder, then use that constant every time you include some asset:

```
define('ASSETS_URL', base_url('assets/'));

// or you can even define separate constants for CSS
define('ASSETS_CSS_URL', base_url('assets/css/'));

// then use it like this
// note the extra slash, base_url() strips trailing slashes
$path_to_css_file = ASSETS_CSS_URL . '/materialize.min.css';
```

Comment: Check the generated URL. It should give you some hints of what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to put all static files inside an "assets" folder inside your web root. Let's say you create a folder called "assets" with folders inside for the specific types, i.e. js, img, css.

Then always refer to them as in the following examples :

- /assets/js/main.js
- /assets/css/style.css
- /assets/img/picture.jpg

Comment: i do this. for default controller it works fine, but for other controllers it add index.php to path of these assetes.

Comment: Then the files for sure are not in the correct place. If the files are in the webroot then the / will make the browser point there by default.

Answer (score 0):

Please autoload `url` helper in autoload.php inside application->config and then link all file via `base_url()`.Put all js and css files in assests folder and then check link code:

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/home/assets/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
```

Answer (score 0):

try this url

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/materialize.min.css">
```

if your base url root directory and your assets folder same as root directory

Comment: i exactly do this. but in other controllers not working.

Comment: where is your assets folder and check url link in browser view page source

Answer (score 0):

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

use this in your view files(header.php)